# Properties Tab only showing World Tab

Tags: interface, properties

My properties tab on the right is only showing the *World* tab and nothing else.

I'm new and don't know how to solve this.

Comment: There's no active object. Select an object in the 3D view

Comment: I've tried that, it didn't do anything.

Comment: Nevermind I have fixed the problem by myself.

Comment: I just needed to click the small pin-looking icon in the top left corner of my _Properties_ panel

Comment: Please do not mark a question as solved without **writing an answer** explaining how you solved it. Others might learn from your experience. Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I have posted one now.

Comment: By the way, sorry for not really knowing the rules of posting on this forum. This was my first post I have made as you probably can see.

Comment: @PsychicGaming you can start by reading: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour . For more detailed ways to make better use of this site: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 3):

You have to click on the small pin-looking icon in the top left corner of your *Properties* panel.

[image]

Comment: Wow wasn't even aware of that feature