# Can't see tabs in weight painting mode

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I can't see some tabs in weight painting mode. I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mZtc33rQ3c&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0djuNM22htmz3BUtHHtOh7v&index=3 and on minute 10:00 can't understand why my tabs aren't there. What's wrong?[image]

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and provide more info about the problem? You have armature selected on the screenshot and neither you can activate Weight Paint interaction mode for it, nor you should. Weights are added on the mesh to the groups which controlled with adjacent bones.

Comment: @MrZak from the outliner icons imho he/she has a parented mesh selected, apparently, not the armature itself. So weight paining should be available, and imho should see a couple more icons... But in the properties panel there's armature > armature and not the parented object... could it be some weird unvalid state...?

Comment: @Liana, please can you specify which blender version are you using?

Comment: @m.ardito i am using v2.78

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65588/properties-tab-only-showing-world-tab. Press on the small white icon in the top left corner of the Properties editor window (just below and to the left of marked area on the screenshot)