# How to import texture on an imported FBX file?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I switch to Blender cycles then import an FBX file of a spaceship,  to start UV unwrapping but when I do the original texture row disappears and leaves me with 'Render', 'Render Layers', 'Scene', 'World' and 'Texture'. However this is a different texture and gives me different options? I was following a tutorial like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k, however, I couldn't get past 2:48 minute mark of the video because all my options/settings change.

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong can you please help.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Looks like you made multiple tabs from the Properties editor disappear and want them back. Make sure at least one object is selected and active. Make also sure tabs in the Properties editor aren't pinned, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65588/properties-tab-only-showing-world-tab